# In a Union Query with repeating joins in queries, is it better to make a view or to repeat the joins in each query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a union query that unions several select queries together. each of the select queries are on entities that all have address info. So, each select statement has the same inner joins to get the the address, state ect. My question is, is it more efficient to repeat those joins in each select statement or should I make a view/temp table first and then reference that in each of my select queries. Here is what I have now, it is repeating the joins for the address info in each.

```
Select 'Individual' As OwnerType, Horizon.Id as HorizonId, Ownership.Id As OwnershipId, Ownership.OwnershipPercentage, (PersonDetails.FirstName + ' ' + PersonDetails.LastName) As Name, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.ZipCode, State.Abbreviation as State
        From Horizon
        Inner Join Ownership On Horizon.Id = Ownership.HorizonId
        Inner Join OwnerXRef On Ownership.Id = OwnerXRef.OwnershipId
        Inner Join OwnerIndividual On OwnerXRef.IndividualId = OwnerIndividual.Id
        Inner Join PersonDetails On OwnerIndividual.IndividualPersonDetailsId = PersonDetails.Id
        Inner Join PersonDetailsAddressXRef On PersonDetails.Id = PersonDetailsAddressXRef.PersonDetailsId
        Inner Join Address On PersonDetailsAddressXRef.AddressId = Address.Id
        Inner Join State On Address.StateId = State.Id

    UNION All

    Select 'Business' As OwnerType, Horizon.Id as HorizonId, Ownership.Id As OwnershipId, Ownership.OwnershipPercentage, OwnerBusinessEntity.Name As Name, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.ZipCode, State.Abbreviation as State
        From Horizon
        Inner Join Ownership On Horizon.Id = Ownership.HorizonId
        Inner Join OwnerXRef On Ownership.Id = OwnerXRef.OwnershipId
        Inner Join OwnerBusinessEntity On OwnerXRef.BusinessEntityId = OwnerBusinessEntity.Id
        Inner Join Address On OwnerBusinessEntity.AddressId = Address.Id
        Inner Join State On Address.StateId = State.Id

    UNION All

    Select 'Gov-BLM' As OwnerType, Horizon.Id as HorizonId, Ownership.Id As OwnershipId, Ownership.OwnershipPercentage, OwnerBureauOfLandManagement.RegionalOffice As Name, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.ZipCode, State.Abbreviation as State
        From Horizon
        Inner Join Ownership On Horizon.Id = Ownership.HorizonId
        Inner Join OwnerXRef On Ownership.Id = OwnerXRef.OwnershipId
        Inner Join OwnerBureauOfLandManagement On OwnerXRef.BureauOfLandManagementId = OwnerBureauOfLandManagement.Id
        Inner Join Address On OwnerBureauOfLandManagement.AddressId = Address.Id
        Inner Join State On Address.StateId = State.Id

    UNION All

    Select 'Trust' As OwnerType, Horizon.Id as HorizonId, Ownership.Id As OwnershipId, Ownership.OwnershipPercentage, OwnerTrust.TrustName As Name, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.ZipCode, State.Abbreviation as State
        From Horizon
        Inner Join Ownership On Horizon.Id = Ownership.HorizonId
        Inner Join OwnerXRef On Ownership.Id = OwnerXRef.OwnershipId
        Inner Join OwnerTrust On OwnerXRef.TrustId = OwnerTrust.Id
        Inner Join Address On OwnerTrust.TrustAddressId = Address.Id
        Inner Join State On Address.StateId = State.Id
```

Comment: I think the right answer is to fix your database schema.

Comment: A view would be easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you Joe. @Robert Harvey, I am open to suggestions. I typed fix your database schema into mssms and it didn't do anything...  The schema is such that there are several types of owners with unique data for each type so I saw either making a owner table with lots of columns, many of them not applying to any given owner. Or have a owner table for each type and have to deal with Union queries whenever I wanted to see all the owner data together. Is there a better way?

Comment: You ask "is it efficient to use a view or repeat ...". Well, at some point you must repeat the joins. A view would allow you to encapsulate that logic in a single place which improves manageability (so long as it is used consistently). But both approaches have the same level of efficiency.  Assuming this information is virtually static, you might consider a materialized (indexed) view. A view-per-type might also be useful. But again - no one knows how you use this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is it more efficient to repeat those joins in each
>   select statement or should I make a view/temp table first and then
>   reference that in each of my select queries.

Using `view` will not change performance as the `view` is expanded within your query and internally the same queries will be used by server.

Use of `temp table` may help but may also render your query slower, this depends on your data distribution. If all the queries use the same subset of data from the repeating part of your query, you'll gain in performance as you will extraxt the repeating data only once, but if the repeating part extract different data for all 4 queries your query can become slower. I'll try to explain using this example:

Suppose you have a database that stores the data of the centrilized post office for the whole country for the past 10 years. It's enormous volume of data.  You need to extract the data regarding only few senders. 4 departments want to extract all the mail sent by their employments last month. So you have 4 tables for 4 departemnts with the persons of every department and additional details regarding aevery department so yo need to write 4 different queries but they differ only in some columns regarding specific department, all the rest is the same and the repeating part has some joins between senders, receivers, documents, options. If you first join these tables and save the result in temporary table it will be some Gb if not Tb and will take a lot to complete, but if you make 4 different queries, every query will return only some rows because the departments are small.

In order to understand what is the best you should know your data. If every query select different rows in the repeating part and you have appropriate indexes it's better use 4 different queries. On contrary, if every repeating part estract almost the same data it's better extract it once, save to temporary table and use it in each query